# CodeIgniter SQL query returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working with CodeIgniter and having the following problem.

My controller has:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('myModel');
        $data['records'] = $this->myModel->getAll();
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
}
```

And my model has:

```
class myModel extends CI_Model {
    function getAll()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get("test");
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Finally, my view contains:

```
<?php 
print_r($records);
foreach ($records as $item): ?>
    <li><?php echo $item->$title?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The result is that I don't see my table as I should. Instead it prints out `Array()`. `$records` has nothing inside it, and I believe it all begins in the controller.

Any suggestion would be of great help!

Comment: Did you capitalize your Modelname? MyModel

Comment: yeap, myModel, MyModel, same result!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem with your code. You simply get an empty database table.

Check the database table named test. If it's empty, put some field values inside it.

You can even use: `echo $this->db->last_query(); die;` after your call to the model in the controller to see what query you are running. I'm sure it is ok.

Comment: this might be it "echo $this->db->last_query();die;" comes empty but i'm pretty sure i inserted some values in the table via phpmyadmin... could this be a connectivity problem with the database?? thanks for your help

Comment: @Manolis "pretty sure" !== "sure" :D check table first ;)

Comment: then echo last query should print your query :P

Comment: I did!! in phpmyadmin the select query states that it found two rows! I also tried with some other tables I was sure they were filled and the result was the same! (about the echo last I thought i expected results but yes it did echo the query actually :) )

Comment: @Manolis so actually you got a right query and right results? still returning Array() ?

Comment: yeap.. (right query + right results in phpmyadmin)... I get the Array() when using the print_r($records); if i delete this I get nothing

Comment: @Manolis try var_export($records); then check your config/database.php if everythings ok compared to what the CI documentation says ;)

Comment: it did return NULL and checked config/database.php but I couldn't figure out what went wrong.. :/

Comment: @Manolis quite unbelievable bug, what CI version are you running? please post your database.php

Comment: 2.1.3 $active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'manolis';
$db['default']['password'] = '****';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ci_series';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';

Comment: $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

Comment: I started another project with some differences on the sql code but i had the same results... to be more specific this: "$q->result_array()" leaves "q" empty

Comment: @Manolis this is really not a CI problem i guess, you may be have some problem with the server itself, and i can't help since it's really a deep bug i think :(

Comment: @Manolis please also enable logs in your CI config.php file and see if somenthing wrong inside i'm trying figuring out how to help you. but in this case you need deep debugging

Comment: @Manolis i told you it was 90% sure a server problem, you're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if you found it helpfull ;) ciao ciao :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to display the log message. Maybe you'll get something.

Try this in your controller:

```
log_message('info', print_r($data,true));
```

And then check the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks everyone for your help and sorry for the trouble... I managed to find a solution by installing a newer version of xampp and that means of php as well..